# Подскажите функцию, похожую на хэш, но короче и без коллизий

Tags: алгоритм, хеширование, множества

Требуется генерировать из последовательных целых, уникальные непоследовательные n-значные коды. Представьте хэши, серийники, или номера купонов. Целочисленному id от 0 до K соответствует строго один n-значный код. И важно, чтобы последовательно идущие коды сильно различались, а не одним-двумя символами.

Пример:

```
0    KXBR6Z
1    8FLWGG
2    PAZT73
```

Из-за коллизий и краткости требуемых кодов, популярные хэш-функции не подходят. Криптостойкость не требуется. Если злодеи разгадают алгоритм, пусть хоть все коды распечатают. Делается для красоты. Хотя, рассмотреть, от чего зависит сложность отгадывания алгоритма по X имеющимся на руках кодам тоже интересно!

**Вопрос:** подскажите *алгоритм / функцию* `f(i) = s` для соответствия между множествами `0..K` и n-значными `ABC123XYZ`. Обратная функция была бы тоже интересна: `f1(s) = i` чтобы из кода получить целое, либо узнать, что код невалиден.

Наверняка, задача не нова, но не придумал, как искать ответ. Требуется human-трансляция. )

P.S. ищу именно "математику", алгоритм, а не способ забить в БД уникальные значения, каждый раз при создании нового, проверяя уникальность.

Comment: А что мешает юзать 16-ричную систему счисления, оставляя нулевые порядки? Уникальные значения, визуально короче чем 10-ричная, упаковать можно больше значений в одинаковое количество порядков

Comment: вопрос:

>А что мешает юзать 16-ричную систему счисления, оставляя нулевые порядки?

ответ:

>Единственное - последовательно идущие коды различаются мало

Comment: А если эту 16-ричную систему исчисления после этого ещёчем-нибудь зашифровать, тогда будет строгое соответствие между n и f(n), и, при правильном выборе алгоритма, результаты будут очень сильно различаться + сложность при взломе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С такой задачей хорошо справляются [шифры подстановки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шифр_подстановки). Первое, что Вам надо сделать - это расширить алфавит (перейти от цифр к буквам, где несколько букв будут соответствовать одной цифре). Если для Вас очень важно скрыть исходные значение, то имеет смысл предварительно зашифровать данные блочным или асиметричным шифрованием.

накидал пример кода с подстановкой, результат:

```
input/encoded/decoded - 123 / efg / 123
input/encoded/decoded - 456 / hij / 456
input/encoded/decoded - 789 / abc / 789
input/encoded/decoded - 012 / def / 012
input/encoded/decoded - 1157232188 / eoiafgpybl / 1157232188
```

сам код:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Substitution {
    private static final int NUMBER_COUNT = 10;
    private static final int LETTER_COUNT = 26;
    private static final int ZERO_ASCII_CODE = 48;
    private static final int A_CHAR_ASCII_CODE = 97;

    // substitution tables
    private static final Map<Character, List<Character>> numToChar = new HashMap<Character, List<Character>>(
            NUMBER_COUNT);
    private static final Map<Character, Character> charToNum = new HashMap<Character, Character>(
            LETTER_COUNT);

    // init tables
    static {
        // add list containers
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_COUNT; i++) {
            numToChar.put(Character.valueOf((char) (ZERO_ASCII_CODE + i)),
                    new LinkedList<Character>());
        }

        // init substitution table
        for (int i = A_CHAR_ASCII_CODE; i < A_CHAR_ASCII_CODE + LETTER_COUNT; i++) {

            // number = (symbol ascii code) mod 9
            Character num = Character
                    .valueOf((char) (i % NUMBER_COUNT + ZERO_ASCII_CODE));
            Character ch = Character.valueOf((char) i);

            numToChar.get(num).add(ch);
            charToNum.put(ch, num);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("dumping straight substitution table");
        for (Character num : numToChar.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("num to char - " + num + ", replacements = "
                    + numToChar.get(num));
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("dumping reverse substitution table");
        for (Character ch : charToNum.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("char to num - " + ch + ", replacements = "
                    + charToNum.get(ch));
        }

        // test
        String[] nums = new String[] { "123", "456", "789", "012", "1157232188" };
        String r = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            r = decode(nums[i], true);
            System.out.println("input/encoded/decoded - " + nums[i] + " / " + r
                    + " / " + decode(r, false));
        }

    }

    public static String decode(String input, boolean direction) {
        // result buffer
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(input.length());

        // ensure all latters are in lower case
        String data = input.toLowerCase();

        // store indexes (determines which letter to use when coding a number)
        Map<Character, Integer> indexes = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        // encode string
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            b.append(decode(indexes, data.charAt(i), direction));
        }

        return b.toString();
    }

    // straight - number to letter
    // reverse - letter to number
    private static Character decode(Map<Character, Integer> indexes, char ch,
            boolean direction) {
        // convert character
        Character character = Character.valueOf(ch);
        if (direction) {
            // get list
            List<Character> list = numToChar.get(character);

            // get index to use
            Integer index = indexes.get(character);
            if (null == index) {
                index = Integer.valueOf(0);
            }

            // update index map
            int next = index.intValue() + 1;
            if (next == list.size()) {
                next = 0;
            }

            indexes.put(character, Integer.valueOf(next));

            return list.get(index);
        }

        return charToNum.get(character);
    }
}
```

Данный пример строго "заточен" под цифры и буквы, но, по аналогии, можно сделать код который будет делать подстановки отдельных символов и/или их последовательностей

Answer (score 4):

- В качестве одного из *плохих* вариантов, который, тем не менее, решает задачу, могу предложить следующий подход *(плох он из соображений, описанных ниже):*

> 1. Кодировать исходный номер купона `N` в [системе кодирования `Base36.`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36)
> 2. Дописывать недостающие нули в начало для того, чтобы получить желаемую длину кода.
> 3. Совершать какие-либо битовые преобразования, чтобы коды для `N` и `N + 1` не выглядели похожими, сохраняющие биективность и эффективную вычислимость обратной функции.

- Сама по себе постановка задачи немного странная - требуется найти *биективную* функцию, для которой существует *эффективно вычислимая* обратная функция ("чтобы из кода получить целое"). В такой постановка любой купон или серийник, выданный пользователю, автоматически уязвим для для реверсинга.

> Если выгода, получаемая с такого купона / серийника / ... окажется достаточной, то наверняка найдется человек, который найдет обратную функцию, а следовательно, **сможет проэксплуатировать систему.**

- Если же снять ограничение на эффективную вычислимость обратной функции, то практически задача теряет смысл, поскольку организовать проверку валидности для произвольно взятого кода купона становится на порядок сложнее.

> Нужно опять каким-то образом сравнивать хэши кодов купонов, исключать коллизии и т.п. Мне кажется, что для кодов типа `KXBR6Z` можно доказать, что с приемлемой с практической точки зрения вероятностью этого не получится. *Хотя, возможно, здесь я упускаю что-то очевидное.* `[?]`

- Вообще говоря, *правильный подход* к задаче такого рода (генерация уникального набора купонов в БД и операции над этой БД) обладает **целым набором преимуществ** по сравнению с решением, где используется некоторая предопределенная функция.

> Попробуйте представить, например, как проставить купону, полученному с помощью некоторой функции, статус `revoked` или `invalid`. Или, скажем, разрешить использовать какой-либо купон дважды.

- Из референсов, которые могут быть полезны:

> - [**Create a set of “coupon codes” based on an algorithm**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956613/create-a-set-of-coupon-codes-based-on-an-algorithm-no-need-to-store-the-codes) (см. про `Partial Key Verification).`
> - [**`[CPAN]` CouponCode.**](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-CouponCode/lib/Algorithm/CouponCode.pm)

Answer (score 1):

У нас две задачи: сгенерировать для каждого купона уникальное число. Это называется perfect hash. Вторая задача - сделать так, чтобы каждому купону соответствовало число от 0 до N-1. Как решить обе эти задачи одним алгоритмом, я не представляю, но по отдельности - вполне.

Код купона состоит из 6 символов, каждый из которых может иметь одно из 36 значений. То есть код представляет собой шестизначное число в 36-ричной системе счисления! К счастью, такое число укладывается в 32 бита. Можешь проверить по калькулятору, что 36^6 < 2^32.

```
unsigned to_hash(const char* coupon)
{
    unsigned hash = 0;
    char c;
    for( int i = 0; i < 6; ++i ) {
        c = coupon[i];
        if( c < 'A' ) {
            c -= '0';
        } else {
            c -= '7';
        }
        hash *= 36;
        hash += c;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Теперь вторая задача - нумерация этих хэшей и поиск номера хэша по самому хэшу. Это очень просто, если заранее составить массив хэшей купонов в возрастающем порядке и определять индекс бинарным поиском. Если индекс не найден - значит, купон некорректный. Если заранее составить массив хэшей невозможно, то задача усложняется, но ненамного. Надо будет использовать индексированный список и сортировку вставками. Но это уже другая история.

Comment: Ещё и требуется, чтобы идущие подряд номера купонов не выглядели последновательностью. Т.е. `000001, 000002, 000003` – не айс.

Comment: То есть купоны ABCDE1 и ABCDE2 должны превращаться в очень разные числа? Достаточно перемешать биты хэша и/или поXORить. Очевидно, что при этом не возникнет коллизий. Вот первое, что пришло на ум:

hash = hash << 22 & (hash & 0x3ffc00) & hash >> 22;
hash ^= 0x811c9dc5;

Answer (score 0):

Без коллизий нельзя (если хеш постоянной длины), на общем наборе данных. Для последовательности чисел, чем md5 с солью и выделение части хеша необходимой длинны не подходит?

upd:
Если алгоритм на серверной стороне, возьми простое: серию, если таковая есть, и свою уникальную соль. Проверку-то, снова будешь на сервере выполнять, в чем тогда отличие от функции. Пример:

```
Серия: 101010
Код: e25019
```

Для них на сервере:

```
Серия:101010
Соль(приватные данные): Yap!
Md5(101010Yap!) = e2501912913cd181d4199bcea5dd401c
Выделил 6 символов. Проверил. И ты не зависишь от коллизий.
```

Единственный минус - утечет соль, или будет слишком маленькая по длине(возможность перебора) - считай, что придется менять алгоритм (менять соль/править настройки безопасности и т.п.).

Comment: В том-то и дело, что нужен не хэш, а внешне похожая ф-я.

Comment: `md5(n) => x;`

нужна функция которая бы сделала: `f(x) => n`, а с `md5` такое не прокатит

Comment: Если сам по себе `md5` хэш [гарантирует практическую уникальность,][1] то на отдельно взятую его часть эта гарантия не распространяется. Доказать можно тривиально, взяв, например, в качестве длины части хэша единицу.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444321/how-are-hash-functions-like-md5-unique

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, существует доля вероятности возникновения коллизий хеша, но при этом присутствует привязка не только к коду(хешу), а и к серийному номеру, что гарантирует уникальность на наборе {0;K} целых, не повторяющихся чисел. Пример. Берем 1 в качестве длины md5 хеша. Получаем наборы: (1Yap!;e);(2Yap!;7)... Даже если где-то будет повторяться хеш, то это в любом случае будет уникальный набор, при условии что серийный номер не повторяется и идет по возрастающей. В этом случае проверка валидности(можно сказать даже цифровая подпись номера) возможна.

Comment: @vv2 

- Мы же в контексте данной задачи рассматриваем не пару `{что-то, фрагмент хэша}`, а просто `{фрагмент хэша}`. То, есть, если, скажем, рассмотреть задачу выдачи купонов или серийников, то идея заключается в том, чтобы соответствующий номер купона можно было напечатать на бумаге и чтобы все такие купоны были практически уникальными.

- Понятно, что для случая с фрагментом `md5` длиной 1 об уникальности говорить не приходится. Или я что-то упускаю? :)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, Задача по сути - получить "цифровую подпись" числа от 0 до K(хотя топикстартер обозначил как уникальную, но при наличии коллизии на ограниченной длине хеша, это не реально). Мы же по сути задействуем само число в паре с ограниченной длиной "хеша-подписи" для создания уникальности, при условии что числа от 0 до K не повторяются. В этом случае атака идет не на хеш, а на пару (число;хеш), при обозначенной длине 6 символов(24 бита), это 2^24 варианта, но при этом сам алгоритм преобразования остается не тронутым. При реализации программы, на базе алго, это нужно учитывать. :)